# how do i create a site that allows users to create and view events?

Tags: 7

I'm creating a site where users should be able to create events that are accessible by all users of the site on an "events" page.....whats the best way to do this? 
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to do this task.

You need to create a new content type. add to it corresponding fields and set to it create/edit/delete permission for anonymous and registered users in the permissions page.

As I see, your are a newer on Drupal. I advice you to go throught the documentation to learn about Drupal, its conception and how it works.